# Push some folders in bitbucket repo to github when running pipelines

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to add pipelines to a bitbucket repo that pushes a foler to github ,
bitbucket-pipelines.yml contains
it's failing on last command push , with error " Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

tryed this on yml:

```
  pipelines:
  branches:
    release:
    - step:
        name: "Build"
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run-script build
        caches:
          - "node"
    - step:
        name: "Build and push to github"
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends git openssh-client
          - git config --global user.name githubRepoUsername
          - git config --global user.email githubRepoUsernameemail
          - cd release
          - git init
          - git remote add github git@github.com:streamdigitalsignage/ocb.git
          - git checkout -b _build
          - git add .
          - git commit -m "Added new version of at $(date)"
          - git push -f github _build
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/streamdigitalsignage/ocb is a private repository, which means your [BitBucket pipeline](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines/) must a private key which will authenticate it as streamdigitalsignage, or a collaborator with access to that repository.

I would recommend creating a dedicated key, and registering its public key in the target account.
Then registering that private key as a secure variable, as described in "[Use multiple SSH keys in your pipeline](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-multiple-ssh-keys-in-your-pipeline/)"

[image: https://images.ctfassets.net/zsv3d0ugroxu/LGI7ja4ik7BxdAn67XFs9/84ae8a48b27d3ccb8f2e5dcb17737c37/adding_multiple_ssh_keys]
(Bitbucket repository, select Repository settings, then under Pipelines, select Repository variables.)

Then you can reference it in your pipeline:

```yaml
pipelines:  
  default:
    - step:
        script:
           - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
           - cat my_known_hosts >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
           - (umask  077 ; echo $MY_SSH_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```